# Unable to unlock encrypted hard drive using the password

Tags: windows-7, disk-encryption, bitlocker

I am trying to unlock my USB hard drive with the password. When I enter the password to unlock the drive, I am receiving the following error message:

> Bitlocker Drive Encryption failed to recover from an abruptly terminated conversion. This could be due to either all conversion logs being corrupted or the media being write-protected.

I have Windows 7.

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/bitlocker-drive-encryption-failed-to-recover-from/232e812b-4f7a-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5 ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing the link. The solution provided on this link was suggested around 2011-2012..Is there any latest update that has helped resolve this issue?

Comment: I have read that Bitlocker repair tool can be used to recover the content. To use this tool, I will need the password to unlock my hard drive, a separate hard drive that equals the size of my hard drive or is bigger than that...Will this help? Can I use this Bitlocker Repair tool on Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

#### Can I use this Bitlocker Repair tool on Windows 7?

> The BitLocker Repair Tool (Repair-bde) is a command-line tool included
>   with Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows 7, Windows Server 2012, and
>   Windows 8. This tool attempts to repair or decrypt a damaged
>   BitLocker-encrypted volume using the supplied recovery information to
>   reconstruct critical parts of the drive and salvage recoverable data
>   to another volume.
>
> This tutorial will show you how to use the BitLocker Repair Tool to
>   recover your data from a damaged encrypted operating system (OS)
>   drive, fixed data drive (ex: internal volume/drive), or removable data
>   drive (ex: USB drive) in **Windows 7** and Windows 8.
>
> You must be signed in as an administrator to be able to do the steps
>   in this tutorial.

Source [How to Use BitLocker Repair Tool to Recover a Drive in Windows 7 and Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/21714-bitlocker-repair-tool-recover-drive-windows-7-8-a.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I was encrypting my hard driver, I was able to set up a password. However, I did not receive any prompt to save the Bitlocker Recovery Key. Now, I just have my password and Recovery Key identification no. Will this be enough to use the Bitlocker Repair tool?

Comment: No idea .... :/